# Best practices to filter in Django

Tags: python, django, filter

In one of the pages of my Django app I have a page that simply displays all employees information in a table:

Like so:

```
First Name: Last Name: Age: Hire Date:
Bob         Johnson    21   03/19/2011
Fred        Jackson    50   12/01/1999
```

Now, I prompt the user for 2 dates and I want to know if an employee was hired between those 2 dates.

For HTTP GET I just render the page and for HTTP POST I'm sending a URL with the variables in the URL.

my urls.py file has these patterns:

```
('^employees/employees_by_date/$','project.reports.filter_by_date'),
('^employees/employees_by_date/sort/(?P<begin_date>\d+)/(? P<end_date>\d+)/$', EmployeesByDate.as_view()),
```

And my filter_by_date function looks like this:

```
def filter_by_date(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    return render(request,"../templates/reports/employees_by_date.html",{'form':BasicPrompt(),})
else:
    form = BasicPrompt(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        begin_date = form.cleaned_data['begin_date']
        end_date = form.cleaned_data['end_date']
    return HttpResponseRedirect('../reports/employees_by_date/sort/'+str(begin_date)+'/'+str(end_date)+'/')
```

The code works fine, the problem is I'm new to web dev and this doesn't feel like I'm accomplishing this in the right way. I want to use best practices so can anyone either confirm I am or guide me in the proper way to filter by dates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, it's a bit awkward to query your API in that way. If you need to add the employee name and something else to the filter, you will end up with a very long URL and it won't be flexible.

Your filter parameters (start and end date) should be added as a query in the url and not be part of path.
In this case, the url would be `employees/employees_by_date/?start_date=xxx&end_date=yyy` and the dates can be retrieved in the view using `start_date = request.GET['start_date]`.

If a form is used with `method='get'`, the input in the form are automatically converted to a query and appended at the end of the url.
If no form is used, parameters need to be encoded with a function to be able to pass values with special characters like `\/ $%`.

Answer (score 1):

Use Unix timestamps instead of `mm/dd/yyyy` dates. A unix timestamp is the number of seconds that have elapsed from Jan 1 1970. ("The Epoch".) So it's just a simple integer number. As I'm writing this, the Unix time is **[1432071354](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/)**.

They aren't very human-readable, but Unix timestamps are unambiguous, concise, and can be filtered for with the simple regex `[\d]+`.

You'll see lots of APIs around the web use them, for example [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3). Scroll down to "time based pagination", those numbers are Unix timestamps.

The problem with `mm/dd/yyyy` dates is ambiguity. Is it `mm/dd/yyyy` (US)? or `dd/mm/yyyy` (elsewhere)? What about `mm-dd-yyyy`?